# How to pipe pandas groupby parts to seaborn distplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I was learning using .pipe method in pandas and wondering if we can use it to plot the distplot for each group of groupby.

## MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# data
np.random.seed(100)
data = {'year': np.random.choice([2016, 2018, 2020], size=400),
        'item': np.random.choice(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot'], size=400),
        'price': np.random.random(size=400)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# distplots
for year in df['year'].unique():
    x = df['price'][df['year'] == year]
    sns.distplot(x, hist=False, rug=True)
```

## Question

Can we get the same plot using pandas groupby and without using for loop?

My attempt:

```
df.groupby('year').pipe(lambda dfx: sns.distplot(dfx['price']))
# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

# df[['year','price']].groupby('year').pipe(sns.distplot)
# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DataFrame'
```

## Required output

Same output as for-loop but using pandas pipe.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also want labels, you can do following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

#iris.groupby('species')['sepal_length'].apply(lambda x:sns.distplot(x,hist=False, rug=False,label = x.name))

iris.groupby('species')['sepal_length']\
    .apply(lambda x: sns.kdeplot(x, label = x.name))

plt.xlabel('sepal_length')
plt.ylabel('kde')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Use `.apply(lambda x: sns.kdeplot(x, label = x.name))` now!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite `pipe`, but you can use `apply`:

```
df.groupby('year')['price'].apply(sns.distplot, hist=False, rug=True);
```

Output (which is the same):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From docstring and [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html), `distplot` has been deprecated and will be removed in seaborn v0.14.0.

Most newer functions (ie [rugplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html), [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html), etc..) include the `hue` parameter which does what you achieved with your for loop or using apply as others replied.

The following will generate the same as `sns.distplot(df.price, hist=False, rug=True)` for each `year`:

```
def distplot(df, x, hue):
    plt_args = dict(x=x, hue=hue, palette='tab10')
    sns.kdeplot(df, **plt_args)
    sns.rugplot(df, **plt_args)

df.pipe(distplot, x='price', hue='year')
```

Note that `pipe` is not required here but shows how it could be used if methods need to be chained before plotting.

[image]